# Help with responsive theme styling issue

Tags: themes, css, html

I'm using a template that has been working fine but have discovered that once the screen size goes over 1200 pixels the images fall out of their grid arrangement. I can't see where this issue lies in the html or CSS. Any support would be appreciated.

[Here is link to my website](http://www.ratedvinyl.com/?product_cat=car-vinyls)

You can see the issue in following images;

[image]

Comment: I can't see what is the error. Above 1200 is just fine. Can you post the screenshot?

Comment: Thanks, I've uploaded an image now thr right hand side is the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Because some of titles are running on to three lines when the screen gets smaller its messing up the flow of the floated elements. What you need to do is clear every fourth element.

Also this is a basic css question and is not specific to Wordpress at all.